# Disown an object created with new

Tags: python, swig

I'm using *swig-3* to create *Python-3-wrappers* for *c++*.

The constructor of class `MyClass` get's a reference to an instance of an owner-object. The constructor registers itself at the owner object.

How can I disown an newly created object?

```
class MyObject{
public:
  MyObject(Owner *owner) {
   owner->register(this);
  }
}
```

[Here](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#Ruby_nn59) is "disown" described:

```
%apply SWIGTYPE *DISOWN {Foo *foo};
void set_foo(Foo *foo);
```

- I don't understand how to apply "disown" to a constructor.
- Is this only valid for Ruby?

Comment: _"Is this only valid for Ruby"_ !? Do you mean Python?

Comment: I meant Ruby: "38.10 Memory Management" talks about Ruby only - althoug the concepts are usefull for Python too.